# Use short datetime in rails collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, time, short

This is a minor annoyance I can't find anything on.

I have a collection select on an Appointment object that shows the times of available appointments:

```
f.collection_select :appointment_id, @available, :id, :time, {:prompt => "Select a time"}
```

This displays using the standard DateTime format: 2011-10-31 08:00:00 UTC 
but I would really prefer the short format, like this:

```
appointment.time.to_s(:short)
```

which displays as 31 Oct 08:00

I can't seem to find the syntax when working with a symbol.  Anybody know this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[While there are hoops you could jump through if you want to maintain the purity of MVC (formatting a date probably isn't what a model should be worried about), I think this is simple enough to be OK.]

Add a method to your model that gives you the string that you want to see.

```
def short_time
  time.to_s(:short)
end
```

Then use `:short_time` as your text_method symbol in `collection_select`.

Comment: You should "accept" this answer to show that it solved your problem (and remove your question from the "not answered" list). You can do that by clicking the "tick" on the left. :)